# sort out all the scripts and css in correct order and without duplicates

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout, bundle

I had following Layout File.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")   


        @*datepicker css resourcese*@
        @*@Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")*@


        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css")

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")

        @*summernote css resourcese*@
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/summernote/summernote.css")



        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")

        @*summernote css resourcese*@
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/summernote/summernote.min.js")

        @*datepicker js resourcese*@

        @*@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js") 
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js")*@ 

        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")
        @RenderSection("head", required: false)


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink(" Test System ", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               ...
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container body-content">

                <div class="row">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>

            <hr />
            <footer>
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="float-middle" style="display: inline; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year Testing Group , Solution by <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="new" class="btlink">Google</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>

                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/base")
                @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

since it has multiple copies of some scripts and CSS .Some of my JavaScript functions and plugins not working smoothly.

So I have to change that layout to like following, to sort out all the scripts and CSS in correct order and without duplicates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")   

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css")

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")

    @*summernote css resourcese*@
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/summernote/summernote.css")

    @RenderSection("head", required: false)


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink(" Test System ", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                         ...
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container body-content">

            <div class="row">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-middle" style="display: inline; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year Testing Group , Solution by <a href="http://www.google.com/" target="new" class="btlink">Google</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/base")

            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")

            @*summernote css resourcese*@
            @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/summernote/summernote.min.js")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

this is my BundleConfig class

```
   public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssjqryUi").Include(
       "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));  

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
                      "~/Content/Site.css"));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/summernote").Include(
         "~/Content/summernote/summernote.css"
         ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/base").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"
               ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/summernote").Include(
               "~/Content/summernote/summernote.js"
               ));
        }
```

are there any other conflicting Script Files or CSS files refer in above layout file and are they in correct order. if not how to sort them in correct order?

**if anyone has to face a situation like this, how to detect these kind same copies of css and script in project , easily without manually checking  ?**

Comment: you add bootstrap.js twice in "~/bundle/base" and ~/bundles/bootstrap"

Comment: @pooriataghizadeh so which line should I erase ?

Comment: remove @Scripts.Render("~/bundle/base") because you added all js in base before.